# How do I impose a "light traffic ban"?

Tags: cities-skylines

I have a region in my city with residential on the left and industrial on the right:

[image: residential on the left, industrial on the right]

The residential area imposes a Heavy Traffic Ban policy to keep those vehicles from clogging the roads. I would *like* the freeway on the right to impose a "Light Traffic Ban", making this pair of freeways serve mutually exclusive types of vehicles.

Can this be done?

Comment: When you invest in a good subway- and bus network, you can drastically reduce the amount of light traffic in your city. Or maybe you could abuse the feature that cars always take the shortest route and make those routes available to heavy traffic deliberately longer than those you want to designate to light traffic.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is no way to do this in the standard game. Additionally, it would appear that, as of two months ago, this is an outstanding request for a mod on the [CS Modding Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylinesModding/comments/2zotxa/request_ban_light_traffic/). So the best answer would be 'not yet.'

That said... in my experience, light traffic tends not to hold up lanes when stopping, is typically A-B, and is relatively quiet and clean compared to heavy traffic.

With careful road design, you shouldn't need to exclude light traffic from areas with industrial and commercial connections - partly as it's more likely to take alternate routes, and partly as it's less of a concern for overall traffic anyway.